# Send form that includes multiple JSON data/files

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, frontend

I developed a form, according the requirements of the client. Now the problem is that I used serveral javascript plugins and I get diferent JSONs data. I mean, one JSON is  the tags plugin, other is the Multi-Image plugin, and so on.

I'd like to use AJAX to send all the data but I don´t get how to do this.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate your JSONs into one. And on the server-side simply parse and use it.

```
function postData() {
    var jsonData= {
        data_type_a: json_a,
        data_type_b: json_b
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'your_url',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            //can show an alert or change an elements text
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    });
}
```